# Expanding the list of relationship field arguments

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I’m looking for a way to expand the list of relationship field arguments, e.g. to add a predicate for each direction of the relation. My first guess was to define a subclass of `models.ForeignKey`

```
class NewForeignKey(models.ForeignKey):

    def __init__(self, parent, pred='', reverse_pred='', **kwargs):
        self.pred = pred,
        self.reverse_pred = reverse_pred
        super(NewForeignKey, self).__init__(parent, **kwargs)
```

Then use this subclass in my models as in the following example:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = NewForeignKey (Question,
                              pred="refers to",
                              reverse_pred="includes",
                              on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Initially, this seemed to work fine, however, when I tried to pass it through `makemigrations` it failed with the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 346, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 445, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 99, in handle
    ProjectState.from_apps(apps),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 178, in from_apps
    model_state = ModelState.from_model(model)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\state.py", line 354, in from_model
    e, 
TypeError: Couldn't reconstruct field question on polls.Choice: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

To make things even simpler I tried from scratch to migrate as follows:

1. first without the FK,
2. then added the FK as `models.ForeignKey` and
3. finally replaced `models.ForeignKey` with `NewForeignKey`

Migrations after step (1) and (2) were successful (obviously). `makemigrations` after step (3) fails all the time with the same result whether I skip step (2) or not.

Digging deeper, I couldn’t find an explanation why this shouldn’t be possible. I understand that Django models have to be subclassed from `django.db.models.Model` ([see here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#model-inheritance)), but this isn’t the case with `models.ForeignKey`.

A clarification on this issue and/or any suggestions for a workaround or a clever alternative that would allow the use of additional relationship field arguments would be appreciated.

Comment: I's not clear which `__init__` call is actually causing the issue. The error is that `__init__` is called without parameter (`self` is always one parameter), so it looks like `parent` is `None` in your `super.__init__` method call? Can you set a breakpoint inside your `NewForeignKey` init method?

Comment: Nope. parent is a Question object not None. Just to clarify this point: When I take the [exmple from the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial02/#creating-models) and modify it in the way described above it works! I just can't makemigrations anymore.

Comment: Just a question, did you have the field as in the example you mention and migrated already? What I would try is migrate back one step in order to remove the migration that creates your question field in the Choice model, then delete that migration and try makemigrations again.

Comment: At first thank you @dirkgroten for your time and effort. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. See the paragraph I have added in my post.

Comment: I'm shooting in the dark here, but I'd suggest to (1) rename `parent` to `to`, as it is in `ForeignKey`; even if it doesn't affect anything it's good if it's consistent; (2) make sure you have a `deconstruct()` method (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-model-fields/#field-deconstruction).

Comment: That's it! Renaming the argument to `to` made the difference. Also introducing a `deconstruct()` method is a good idea. Thanks Antonis.